# How to (un)star all messages in conversations view?

Tags: gmail

Is there a keyboard shortcut or keyboard combination to (un)star all messages of a conversations thread in conversations view (i.e. not from the inbox view)?

[image: star/unstar all messages using a keyboard shortcut]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't.

The closest that you can get with straight-up Gmail is to

1. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> to "star" the current message
2. Hit <kbd>N</kbd> (or <kbd>P</kbd>) to move the focus to the Next (or Previous) message in the conversation
3. Go to step #1; repeat until you run out of messages

Not ideal for more than half-a-dozen or so messages, since when fully collapsed ("show X more messages") the focus seems to pick one in that bunch at random rather than expanding the bunch so you can see all of the stars. It's also a bummer if you use multiple stars, since you need to hit <kbd>S</kbd> repeatedly to cycle through them.

Comment: Thank you. I will address this as a Gmail feature request to the devs.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to un-star a bunch of conversations (assumes **keyboard shortcuts** is enabled) - in the **Threadlist Selection** screen:

1. Use the search bar to select the conversations you want to un-star.  For example, to un-star conversations with the label `foo`, search for:

   ```
   label:foo   is:starred
   ```
2. use the <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> keys to move down and up the list
3. use the <kbd>s</kbd> key to un-star (or re-star) each conversation